# How do I structure my data to match the structure of the diabetes dataset in R?

Tags: r

I'd like to structure my own data similar to the diabetes dataset in the monomvn package of R to try out some different regression model examples (specifically, LASSO regression).

The diabetes data lists three variables (x, x2, and y), but both x and x2 contain several sub-levels of variables (such as age, bmi, etc.). These x and x2 variables are called in different regression model examples that ultimately reference these sub-levels of variables.

Unfortunately, any time that I try to structure my data to match the diabetes data set, it either is coerced to a list within the variable (which prevents the examples from working as they should), or does not get classified into the single x variable (instead reading each variable individually as x.age, x.bmi, etc.). My goal is to be able to use df$x to reference multiple variables; in other words, df$x should reference df$x.var1, df$x.var2, df$x.var3. I have up to 240 variables that I'd like to code within a single x variable.

The closest I could get is:

```
df$x.var1 <- data.frame(as.numeric(master_data$var1))
df$x.var2 <- data.frame(as.numeric(master_data$var2))
df$x.var3 <- data.frame(as.numeric(master_data$var3))
```

No errors in creating the data frame; however, I still need to reference the whole variable name (x.var1) instead of "x" that refers to all of the sub-variables in order for any of the regression examples to work; with that approach, I can't list ~240 variable names as x variables in the lasso regression models.

In Matlab, I would structure this as a structure of sub-variables (var1, var2, var3, etc.) within a structure named "x"; however, I'm doing this in R and am currently unable to see how I could complete that type of task.

The diabetes data set I'm referencing is found here:

```
library(monomvn)
data(diabetes)
```

If it's helpful, the diabetes data set classifies the "x" and "x2" variables "AsIs" (although all sub-variables appear to be numeric) while "y" is numeric.

FYI, I do have some NA values in my own data set, but I haven't received any errors that makes me think that has something to do with this issue; however, the diabetes data set does not have NA values, so I'm not ruling out the possibility.

If anyone could provide some guidance about how to put numeric data into a format that matches the diabetes data set, that would be incredibly helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The [man page](https://rdrr.io/cran/lars/man/diabetes.html) describes the data as a data.frame containing the following columns: x a matrix with 10 columns,  y a numeric vector, and x2 a matrix with 64 columns.

The problem is you're trying to assign the data as columns of the data.frame. You need to first assemble the two matrices and then assign them to the data.frame.

Something like this:

```
mydata.x <- matrix(runif(500,-2,2),ncol=10)
mydata.y <- runif(50,50,500)
mydata.x2 <- matrix(runif(3200,-2,2),ncol=64)
mydiabetes <- data.frame(mydata.x,mydata.y,mydata.x2)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply -- unfortunately, this yields something similar to what I've been able to create previously, which is a data.frame with 75 variables instead of just three variables that encode the other numerous variables within those three variables. 

I do get closer to what I need when I use:
`mydiabetes <- list(mydata.x,mydata.y,mydata.x2)`
which yields a list with three variables.

However, when I change it to a data frame from there, it reverts to 75 variables. How can I keep it to just the three variables?